# how to display mannually uploaded image in firebase storage in html page using vanilla javascript. i want the url of image

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

```
import { getStorage, ref, listAll } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-storage.js";

const storage = getStorage();

// Create a reference under whi`your text`ch you want to list
const listRef = ref(storage, '');

// Find all the prefixes and items.
listAll(listRef)
.then((res) =\> {

    res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
      // All the items under listRef.
    console.log(itemRef)
      })
      
      
    });
```

i tried in getting url of image from firebase, which the image is manualy uploaded

Comment: Did you see the Firebase documentation on [getting files via a URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.